# jqgrid - pagination

Tags: json, jqgrid

I have the following JSON structure

**JSON**

```
{
   "page":"1",
   "total":"3",
   "records":"15",
   "mypage":{
      "outerwrapper":{
         "innerwrapper":{
            "rows":[
               {
                  "id":"1",
                  "read": true,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                         "label":"linkimg",
                         "links": [
                             {
                                 "name":"link1"
                             },
                             {
                                 "name":"link2"
                             },
                             {
                                 "name":"link3"
                             }
                         ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"2",
                  "read": false,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"3",
                  "read": false,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"4",
                  "read": false,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"5",
                  "read": false,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"6",
                  "read": false,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"7",
                  "read": false,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"8",
                  "read": false,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"9",
                  "read": false,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"10",
                  "read": false,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"11",
                  "read": false,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"12",
                  "read": false,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"13",
                  "read": false,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"14",
                  "read": false,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"15",
                  "read": true,
                  "cells": [
                     {
                        "label":"linkimg",
                        "links": [
                           {
                              "name":"link1"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"link2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Please note:** that `page`, `total` and `records` for pagination are defined **before** `mypage`. This works. I get `Page 1 of 3, 2 of 3 and 3 of 3`. BUT

If I place `page`, `total` and `records` for pagination **after** `outerwrapper`, **then it doesn't work.** I get `Page 0 of 3`

```
{
   "mypage":{
      "outerwrapper":{
         "page":"1",
         "total":"3",
         "records":"15",
         ....
         ....
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want change the place of `page`, `total` and `records` inside of your JSON input data you have to inform jqGrid about the new place. You can do this using [jsonReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#json_dat). For example you can add the following `jsonReader` to the list of parameters of jqGrid

```js
jsonReader: {
    page: 'mypage.outerwrapper.page',
    total: 'mypage.outerwrapper.total',
    records: 'mypage.outerwrapper.records'
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me with this one? I'm stuck on this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618691/jqgrid-how-to-map-cell-data-to-column-model-if-column-model-is-in-json-respons