# jqgrid - toolbar text - is this a good way of doing it?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have specified `userdata` in JSON response. Depending on the value of the `title` property,

- the caption will change to reflect the value of the `title` property
- the text in the toolbar (between the grid caption and data table headers) will change

**HTML**

```
<table id="myjqgrid"></table>
<div id="Pager"></div>
```

**JSON**

```
{
    "colModel": [
        {
            "name": "ID",
            "label": "ID",
            "width": 60,
            "align": "left",
            "jsonmap": "cells.0.value",
            "sortable": true      
        },
        {
            "name": "FirstName",
            "label": "FirstName",
            "width": 100,
            "align": "left",
            "jsonmap": "cells.1.value",
            "sortable": false       
        },
        {
            "name": "LastName",
            "label": "LastName",
            "width": 100,
            "align": "left",
            "jsonmap": "cells.2.value",
            "sortable": false       
        }
    ],
    "colNames": [
        "ID",
        "FirstName",
        "LastName"
    ],
    "mypage": {
        "outerwrapper": {
            "page":"1",
            "total":"1",
            "records":"20",
            "innerwrapper": {
                "rows":[
                    {
                        "id":"1",
                        "cells":
                        [               
                            {
                                "value":"12345",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"David",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Smith",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"2",
                        "cells":
                        [               
                           {
                                "value":"37546",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Willy",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Peacock",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"3",
                        "cells":
                        [               
                            {
                                "value":"62345",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Kim",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Holmes",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"4",
                        "cells":
                        [      
                            {
                                "value":"186034",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Andy",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Wills",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"5",
                        "cells":
                        [              
                            {
                                "value":"67345",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Paul",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Lawrence",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"6",
                        "cells":
                        [              
                            {
                                "value":"12906",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Andy",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Charlery",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"7",
                        "cells":
                        [              
                            {
                                "value":"564565",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Bets",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Josilyn",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    }
                ],
                "userdata": {
                    "title": "My Title 1"     // this can be 'My Title 1' or 'My Title 2'                   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**JQGrid Definition**

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "myjqgrid.json",
        data: "",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            var columnData = response.mypage.outerwrapper,
                columnNames = response.colNames,
                columnModel = response.colModel;

            $("#myjqgrid").jqGrid({
                datatype: 'jsonstring',
                datastr: columnData,                
                colNames: columnNames,
                colModel: columnModel,
                jsonReader: {
                    root: "innerwrapper.rows", 
                    userdata: "innerwrapper.userdata",             
                    repeatitems: false
                },
                gridview: true,
                pager: "#Pager",
                rowNum: 21,
                rowList: [21],
                viewrecords: true,              
                recordpos: 'left',
                multiboxonly: true,
                multiselect: true,
                width: "1406",      
                height: "auto",
                loadonce: true, 
                toolbar: [true,"top"],  
                loadComplete: function(){
                    var userdata = $("#myjqgrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'userData');
                    if (userdata) {
                        if (userdata.title) {
                            $("#myjqgrid").jqGrid('setCaption', userdata.title);
                        }
                    }
                    if (userdata.title === "My Title 1") {
                        $("div#t_myjqgrid").append("Viewing the Records.");
                    } else if (userdata.title === "My Title 2") {
                        $("div#t_myjqgrid").append("Editing the Records.");
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#myjqgrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#Pager', {add:false, edit:false, del:false, position: 'right'});
        }
    });
});
```

**My Question is**

Is this the right way of changing the content of `div#t_myjqgrid`? Or does jqgrid offer a property/method/event that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no methods for changing of content top or bottom toolbars added by `toolbar` option of jqGrid, but you can use `setCaption` to set grid caption (title). The small modified [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SK11-8.htm) of your code uses the following `loadComplete`:

```
loadComplete: function () {
    var $this = $(this), userdata = $this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'userData');
    if (userdata && userdata.title) {
        $this.jqGrid('setCaption', userdata.title);
    }
    if (userdata.title === "My Title 1") {
        $this.jqGrid('setCaption', "Viewing the Records.");
        $('#t_' + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id))
            .append('<div style="margin: 0.3em">Viewing the Records.</div>');
    } else if (userdata.title === "My Title 2") {
        $this.jqGrid('setCaption', "Editing the Records.");
        $('#t_' + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id))
            .append('<div style="margin: 0.3em">Editing the Records.</div>');
    }
}
```

The usage of `$.jgrid.jqID(this.id)` instead of `this.id` is helpful in the case if the `id` of the grid (in you case 'myjqgrid') contains some [meta-characters](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).