# How to add second row in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Currently I have the following jqgrid structure:

```
colName:['ID','Name'],
colModel:[ {<ID CODE HERE>},{<NAME CODE HERE>}],
<REST OF CODE HERE>
```

The above jqgrid displays fine as follows:

```
ID    Name
1     Name1
2     Name2
```

I want to display one row above it with dynamic data. Such as:

```
Period
From 10/10/2013 To 10/10/2014
ID    Name
1     Name1
2     Name2
```

The "Period" row is static word while the row below it "From 10/10/2013 To 10/10/2014" is dynamic data coming from backend just like Name1, and Name2 etc.

How can I display these two rows above it?

Comment: you can use `Group Column Headers` for example, see their docs on how to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two standard element of grid which can be created over column headers: *caption* (grid header) and *top toolbar* (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:how_it_works) for pictures with examples). Both the headers can hold any common HTML data inclusive `<br/>`.

Initial caption can be created by usage non-empty `caption` parameter. You can change it at any moment using [setCaption](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) method.

To create top toolbar you should include `toolbar: [true, "top"]` option. It create additional div over the grid header. The div have the class `"ui-userdata"` and the id constructed based on the id of the grid: "t_" + grid_id. If you need to place multiline information in the div you should overwite default CSS. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19728244/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9310762/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8688224/315935) for more details and code examples.